# Passing a prompt via python to llama.cpp

Tags: python, llama

I have written the following code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import mysql.connector
from dotenv import load_dotenv


def run_llama_cpp(prompt):
    # Specify the absolute path of the executable and current directory
    executable_path = 'D:\\Code\\llama_cpp\\w64devkit\\w64devkit.exe'
    current_directory = 'D:\\Code\\llama_cpp\\llama.cpp'
    model_path = 'D:\\Code\\llama_cpp\\llama.cpp\\models\\llama-2-7b.Q8_0.gguf'

    # Debug: Print the current working directory
    print("Current Working Directory:", os.getcwd())

    # Change directory
    os.chdir(current_directory)
    print("Changed to Directory:", os.getcwd())

    # Define the command
    command = [
        executable_path,  # Use the absolute path of your executable
        './main',
        '-ins',
        '--color',
        '-c', '1024',
        '--temp', '0.7',
        '--repeat_penalty', '1.1',
        '-s', '42',
        '-n', '-1',
        '-m', model_path,
        '-p', "'" , prompt , "'"
    ]

    try:
        print("Command: ", ' '.join(command))

        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        if stderr:
            print("Standard Error Output:", stderr)

        if process.returncode != 0:
            print("Error running llama_cpp:", stderr)
            return None
        else:
            title_start = stdout.find('[TITLE_START]') + len('[TITLE_START]')
            title_end = stdout.find('[TITLE_END]')
            description_start = stdout.find('[DESCRIPTION_START]') + len('[DESCRIPTION_START]')
            description_end = stdout.find('[DESCRIPTION_END]')

            title = stdout[title_start:title_end].strip()
            description = stdout[description_start:description_end].strip()

            return title, description
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"File not found: {e}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

load_dotenv()
db_connection = os.getenv('DB_CONNECTION')
db_host = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
db_port = int(os.getenv('DB_PORT'))
db_database = os.getenv('DB_DATABASE')
db_username = os.getenv('DB_USERNAME')
db_password = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_host, user=db_username, password=db_password, database=db_database, port=db_port)
cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts")
prompts = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
connection.close()

for prompt_entity in prompts:
    str = prompt_entity['content']
    content = "Generate headline for this content: '" + str + "'. Put the headline between [TITLE_START] and [TITLE_END]"

    title, description = run_llama_cpp(content)
    if title and description:
        print("Content:", content)
        print("Title:", title)
        print("Description:", description)
        print("####################################")
```

I am trying to pass my prompt directly via `w64devkit.exe`, however when I open the command on a regular terminal `w64devkit` opens its own terminal.

[image]
How to pass my prompt directly to llama.cpp and receive the answer?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: You've done the quotes incorrectly, but you shouldn't need them at all.  The whole point of passing arguments as a list is that the parameters have already been separated.  Even if the prompt has spaces, the process will see it as one parameter.  So, just use `'-p', prompt`.  In the worst case, `'-p', "'"+prompt+"'"`.